# How to pass list of strings from JMeter to Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, jmeter

I want to pass a pointer to list of strings from JMeter to my Java code written in Eclipse, since I want to perform operations on that list.

Is that possible to pass list of strings? If so, what should be the way to pass it and what to write in the prototype line of the function?

This is how I create the list in JMeter:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
props.put("myListKey", myList);
```

And this is how I call it in another sampler in JMeter and perform operations on it:

```
List<String> myList = props.get("myListKey");
```

I want to perform the operations on the list in Eclipse and return it to JMeter, is it possible?

How can I pass `myList` to my Java code written in Eclipse?

Comment: jmeter runs in different jvm process and eclipse in different one, what you are asking is inter process communication, there are ways to do that, but do you really want to do that? telling what you want to do with that list will yield some answers.

Comment: I want to add to list values according to many many criteria, all of them are in java with classes, and for my usability it will be helpful to do it in one place, is it even possible to pass it in Jmeter? , can you elaborate how?

Comment: Extend jmeter with plugin/sampler and those many many classes into it.

Comment: Sorry Sagar I did not understand your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is just an IDE for development. You mean your code (I assuming in Java) you are compiling with Eclipse and load to JMeter lib as a jar.

If your method is for example in MyClass java file looks like:

```
 public static myMethod(List<String> list)
```

Just call it in JSR223 element:

```
 MyClass.myMethod(myList);
```